# Virtualenv uses wrong python, even though it is first in $PATH

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I had a problem where `python` was not finding modules installed by pip while in the virtualenv.

I have narrowed it down, and found that when I call `python` when my virtualenv in activated, it still reaches out to `/usr/bin/python` instead of `/home/liam/dev/.virtualenvs/noots/bin/python`.

When I use `which python` in the virtualenv I get:

`/home/liam/dev/.virtualenvs/noots/bin/python`

When I look up my `$PATH` variable in the virtualenv I get:

`bash: /home/liam/dev/.virtualenvs/noots/bin:/home/liam/bin:/home/liam/.local/bin:/home/liam/bin:/home/liam/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory`

and yet when I actually run `python` it goes to `/usr/bin/python`

To make things more confusing to me, if I run `python3.5` it grabs python3.5 from the correct directory (i.e. `/home/liam/dev/.virtualenvs/noots/bin/python3.5`)

I have not touched `/home/liam/dev/.virtualenvs/noots/bin/` in anyway. `python` and `python3.5` are still both linked to `python3` in that directory. Traversing to `/home/liam/dev/.virtualenvs/noots/bin/` and running `./python`, `./python3` or `./python3.5` all work normally.

I am using `virtualenvwrapper` if that makes a difference, however the problem seemed to occur recently, long after install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: Run `alias` on the command line to see if `python` has been aliased.

Comment: AH thank you! this was the problem.

Comment: Please post the solution, as this is an interesting Q.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't get the program that `which` says you should get, you need to look higher up the chain than the platform executor. Shells typically have a way to alias commands and on most unixy shells you can just enter `alias` to see which commands have been remapped. Then its just a matter of going to the config files for your shell and removing the alias.

Sometimes people alias `python` to try to sort out which python they should be using. But there are usually other, better ways. On my linux machine, for example, `python3` is in the path but is a symlink to the real python I am using.

```
td@mintyfresh ~ $ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
td@mintyfresh ~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Feb 17  2016 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4
td@mintyfresh ~ $
```

This is nice because non-shell programs running python get the same one I do and virtual environments work naturally.

Comment: I don't see an example use of `alias` in your answer. You talk about one thing then show examples of another which is confusing, is all. Sorry if I failed to communicate what I meant right away.

Comment: @AdamJagosz - I am advising against aliasing python so there isn't a need to show how to do it. I showed an example of how linux debs and rpms usually handle the problem of aliasing using symlinks instead.

Comment: @AdamJagosz in case this helps, aliases are commonly set up in your `~/.bashrc` or similar file (depending on your shell). I'm not sure if Python installers put aliases there, but in my case *I* put one there by mistake.

Answer (score 57):

My problem was that i recently **moved** my project with virtualenv to another location, due to this `activate` script had **wrong** `VIRTUAL_ENV` path.

```
$ cat path_to_your_env/bin/activate

... # some declarations

VIRTUAL_ENV="/path_to_your_env/bin/python"  # <-- THIS LINE
export VIRTUAL_ENV

... # some declarations
```

To fix this, just update `VIRTUAL_ENV` in `activate` script.

Also you maybe need to fix first line of your `bin/pip` to link to real python path.

Comment: I had renamed my project folder name and faced the same issue.

Comment: I can relate. That actually helped me.

Comment: If I may add a point, what you need to specify at VIRTUAL_ENV is the path to your virtual environment, and not where python is located

Comment: Thank you! Looked everywhere. Hard to put this problem in words. So simple

Comment: that worked for me, though i don't remember moving anything around.

Comment: FWIW, I think that my problem came from the fact that the path was correct but contained special characters, like "é". It happened on a freshly created venv so don't think it has do to with some moving around. Didn't investigate thoroughly but creating a new venv in another path with no special characters worked.

Answer (score 14):

As [tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney) suggested in the comments, I ran `alias` and found that I had previously aliased `python` to `/usr/bin/python3.5` in my `.bashrc`.

I removed that alias from my `.bashrc`, ran `unalias python`, and `source ~/.bashrc` and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

On Cygwin, I still have a problem even after I created symlink to point `/usr/bin/python` to `F:\Python27\python.exe`. Here, after `source env/Scripts/activate`, `which python` is still `/usr/bin/python`.

After a long time, I figured out a solution. Instead of using `virtualenv env`, you have to use `virtualenv -p F:\Python27\python.exe env` even though you have created a symlink.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the same problem. Virtualenv was created in Windows, now I'm trying to run it from WSL.
In virtualenv I renamed python.exe to python3.exe(as I have only python3 command in WSL). In $PATH my virtualenv folder is first, there is no alias for python. I receive `which python3
/usr/bin/python3`. In `/usr/bin/python3` there is symlink `python3 -> python3.6. I suppose it doesn't matter for order resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem.
I ran:

```
virtualenv -p /venv/bin/python3 env
```

and got a permission denied.
so i tried:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /venv/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

`which python` and `print(sys.executable)`
were not agreeing for me. This meant that with an active virtualenv `pip install <package>` would install to the virtualenv, but running `python` would be the base install.

I eventually got around this by running

```
virtualenv -p \path\to\python.exe --always-copy <venvName>
```

I'm not sure if specifying the path to the original python is really necessary, but can't hurt.  According to the man page:

```
 --copies, --always-copy       try to use copies rather than symlinks, even when symlinks are the default for the platform (default: False)
```

I'm using windows powershell with msys64.

Answer (score 0):

A reason for this could also be wrong file permissions. For example if the environment had been restored from a backup with the wrong permissions, like it was in my case. Without executable rights in your own environment, it falls back to the default path. After changing permissions with

```
chmod -R 755 py3Env/
```

the correct python executable in my environment was chosen again.