# python, python3, python3.7 files don't work in a venv (can't be activated)

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.7, python-venv, python-install

I am trying to run some code inside a server. In that server, we use **docker images** to create notebooks inside directories, with commands like:

`docker run -it --gpus "device=1" -p 8886:8886 -v /folder/directory:/workspace/work --name container-name --shm-size=60g --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit stack=67108864 --rm imageid jupyter notebook --port=8886 --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --no-browser`

Once created the notebook with an image, we have **two different environments** with two different python versions in the folder that were designed to execute the code inside `/folder/directory`: `venv3.6` and `venv3.7`.

Even if I didn't create them, I am confident that **the environments worked at some point** (there are checkpoints obtained from the execution of the code by a colleague that worked on it before me). However, it must have been messed up with at some point, maybe after some modifications on the libraries of the docker image.

**The problem** is that, whenever I try to activate `venv3.7` by using `source ./venv3.7/bin/activate` and run a script with `python script_name.py`, the **python version** that is executed is not 3.7, but rather 3.6.10. When going into `/venv3.7/bin/activate` and trying to access or download the *python*, the *python3* or the *python3.7* files, **they cannot be accessed, moved or activated** (i.e., if I enter `/venv3.7/bin/python3.7` on the terminal, I obtain the `file not found` error).

When the environment is activated:

```
root@XXXX:/workspace/work/path# which python
/opt/conda/bin/python

root@XXXX:/workspace/work/path# source ./venv3.7/bin/activate
(venv3.7) root@XXXX:/workspace/work/path#
```

Following [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524320/virtualenv-uses-wrong-python-even-though-it-is-first-in-path), I make the following comprobations

```
(venv3.7) root@XXXX:/workspace/work/path# python -V
Python 3.6.10 :: Anaconda, Inc.

(venv3.7) root@XXXX:/workspace/work/path# echo $PATH
/workspace/work/path/venv3.7/bin:/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/bin:/opt/conda/bin:/opt/cmake-3.14.6-Linux-x86_64/bin/:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/ucx/bin:/opt/tensorrt/bin

(venv3.7) root@XXXX:/workspace/work/path# which python
/opt/conda/bin/python

(venv3.7) root@XXXX:/workspace/work/path# alias
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Which shows that the path is added correctly and there is **no alias for python** that could be messing with the activation but, still, *python* command uses the version from `/opt/conda/bin/python` instead of `/workspace/work/path/venv3.7/bin`

I also have checked that the path `VIRTUAL_ENV` in `activate` script (`venv3.7/bin/activate`) is correct.

I noticed that the directory: `/venv3.7/pyvenv.cfg` contains:

```
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.7.5
```

And when I go to the directory `/usr/bin`, which should contain the python in which the environment is based, it only has python2.7 files. Could that mean that, when the first directory in `$PATH` is followed, **no valid version** of Python is found?

My guess is that the python (*python*, *python3*, *python3.7*) files were symlinks that were broken because the python version changed in `/usr/bin`. However, I don't want to risk to update the version of python in that directory, because it would probably change the default python in `/opt/conda/bin/python` instead, and I don't know much about docker images. Do you think it would work? In that case, how would I do it?

As additional info, the python files inside `venv3.6/bin` seems to work well (it can be executed and copied), but maybe because `/venv3.6/pyvenv.cfg` leads to the default python instead (in `/opt/conda/bin/python`). Also, after asking the original creator of the code, she doesn't know how to solve this issue either.

I need the environment to work, and recreating it is problematic, since many libraries were downloaded from different places (it was delicate work).

What do you suggest?

**EDIT**

I have tried recreating the environment with the python version I need (3.7.5). Do you know of an easy way to **install the same libraries** than in the other environment, considering that I can't activate it?

I was thinking to **use the folders** with the libraries located in `/venv3.7/lib`, but It is not straight forward. Any idea on how to do it?

Also, would you recommend me to create the new environment with `virtualenv` (to have a separate python version) or, rather, with `anaconda`?

Thank you so much for reading me!

Answer (score 0):

After checking the `python3.7` file in the environment:

```
root@XXXX:/# cd workspace/work/path/venv3.7/bin

root@XXXX:/workspace/work/path/venv3.7/bin# stat python
  File: python -> python3.7
  Size: 9               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: XXXX      Inode: XXXX    Links: 1
Access: (XXXX)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-12-06 10:31:18.165001523 +0000
Modify: 2022-05-20 12:28:37.481538688 +0000
Change: 2022-05-20 12:28:37.481538688 +0000
 Birth: -

root@XXXX:/workspace/work/path/venv3.7/bin# stat python3.7
  File: python3.7 -> /usr/bin/python3.7
  Size: 18              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: XXXX      Inode: XXXX    Links: 1
Access: (XXXX)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-12-06 10:31:18.165001523 +0000
Modify: 2022-05-20 12:28:37.481538688 +0000
Change: 2022-05-20 12:28:37.481538688 +0000
 Birth: -
```

It became obvious that, as stated in the post, `/usr/bin` should be the directory where `python3.7` should be installed. That means the problem could be solved by installing it in that folder.

As I didn't know that was the default folder for the Python installation, I tried **installing python from source** as exposed in several guides. However, even if now the environment started accessing `python3.7` in the folder, that installation didn't work either.

So I just tried `apt-get install python3.7`. It took around 10 seconds and, when I tried the code again, it worked!

Next time, when your environments fails because the wrong `python` version is executed, and the aliases and $PATH are right (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524320/virtualenv-uses-wrong-python-even-though-it-is-first-in-path?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more details), just remember to check where the `python` files in the environment point to and verify that the python installation is correct!

I hope this is useful for you.