# `which python3` vs `python3` inconsistency

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, macos, terminal

That is what I observe in my mac, iterm2:

```
> /usr/bin/python3 --version
python3.8.9
> python3 --version
Python3.8.9
> `which python3` --version
Python3.10.8
> which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Could anyone please explain why `which python3` could return a path to the executable different from the executable run by mere `python3`?

I messed my system a bit with too many pythons, so I was about to clean it, when I discovered this inconsistency. One of the pythons must have been installed with brew, another with conda. But shouldn't `which command` always return a path to the executable run by mere `command`?

Comment: What is the output of `type python3`? `echo $PATH`? `hash python3`? Does it persist after `hash -r`?

Comment: `type python3` -> `python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3`
`echo $PATH` -> `/Users/foo/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/foo/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/foo/.local/bin`

Comment: @KamilCuk after running `hash python3` and `hash -r` all got consistent.

Comment: @KamilCuk, if `hash` thing is related to that inconsistency, I think posting an answer with more clarifications would be great :)

Comment: It could be that "python3" is a command alias in your .bashrc (or whatever mac uses).

Comment: run `alias` to see if python3 is there.

Comment: If that's the case, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524320/virtualenv-uses-wrong-python-even-though-it-is-first-in-path/41524530#41524530

Comment: @tdelaney `alias` returns nothing

Comment: Strange. One usually has `ll` at the least. I am a linux user, not mac, so can't test.

Comment: I think @KamilCuk gave the right hint. after running `hash python3` and `hash -r` the problem disappeared, would be great to wrap it up in some answer